Woocommerce Show how many sold in the past X days in the product page
I am using a snippet to show how many items sold for the product in the frontend which displays perfectly.
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wp_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wp_product_sold_count() {
global $product;
$total_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
if ( $total_sold ) echo '
' . sprintf( __( 'Sold', 'woocommerce' ), $total_sold ) . '

';
}

Now what am trying to show in the product page is, how many items were sold in the past x days.
Is there any snippet that I can use to do so?
Thanks

Kindly, we expect you to better search and provide a real related code attempt. Note that stack overflow is not a free coding service.

@LoicTheAztec Thank you for your comment, and I apologize if I misunderstood the platform. I have tried to a deep search but am unable to find anything like this. Either I am using the wrong terms or I really could not find anyone who posted a same questions. Again, my apologies.

In database, there is a table name wc_order_product_lookup. We can fetch the products and order data using the select query.
So, to find the number of times a product sold in the last X days, try the following code,
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'gs_display_count_product_sold' );
function gs_display_count_product_sold(){
    $days = 10;
    printf("Total Sold in last %d days: %d",$days,gs_count_product_sold($days, get_the_ID()));
}
function gs_count_product_sold($days, $product_id) {
    global $wpdb;

    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT count(product_id) 
                FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}wc_order_product_lookup`
                WHERE `date_created` >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL %d DAY ) and `product_id` = %d", 
                array( $days, $product_id)
            )
        );
    return $count;
}

The code was tested and worked.

Thanks a lot brother. I had couple issues with the code and I have contacted the author to see if it worked. If so I will post the answer here for anyone with the same request.
